# How do I have a username-less login where you only need PW in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this is not super secure at all but how would I make a rails page only viewable if correct password is supplied.

It’s for a basic blog or “posts” model.

For the add post / edit post views   I only want visitors to be able to view them if they supply correct password on a one field (password) form.

User enters correct password, they can view the add post / edit post routes.

I plan to save pw as environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about Rails is that it has all kinds of things built in to handle situations like this. In this case it is the [`ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html)

> Makes it dead easy to do HTTP Basic authentication.

Following is a basic example of how to use it, notice the `except :index` that does what it says, it excluded the `index` action from authentication, which might or might not be what you want, you can configure that to your needs.

```rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: :index

  def index
    render plain: "Everyone can see me!"
  end

  def edit
    render plain: "I'm only accessible if you know the password"
  end
end
```